# Local continuous integration system for C++?

Tags: c++, continuous-integration

"local continuous integration system" may not be the correct term, but what I'm hoping to find is an continuous integration system that can be configured to monitor changes to local files (C++ files in particular) and 1) try to compile the affected object files (stopping on first failure), and if successful and no new source file changes 2) link the affected binaries, and if successful and no new source file changes 3) run affected tests.

By monitor changes to local files, I do not mean monitor commits to a revision control system, but the state of local files as they are saved.  Ideally the system would be provide integrations into source editors so it could monitor changes in the editor that haven't even been saved to disk yet.

Ideally it would also provide a graphical indication (preferably on Windows 7) of current and recent status that quickly allows drilling into failures when desired.

The closest thing I found was [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) as described [here](http://dabapps.com/blog/python-tools-local-continuous-integration/) but that only covers running Python tests not building C++ files.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing to what you are looking for is [cdash](http://www.cdash.org/) and the [Boost test bench](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html); I think that a tool like the one you are looking for will never exist for C++ because compiling each project after editing a single file it's only a waste of time in a productive C++ workflow.

Comment: I upvoted this for adding to the discussion by sharing loosely relevant links, but I disagree with the assessment that it will never exist.  I think it should be feasible to restart building in the event of more recent changes.  Also my goal here is to trade machine time for developer time by minimizing the amount of time a developer (i.e. me) needs to spend waiting on builds to complete.

Comment: split your codebase into multiple libraries, this is an effective way to spend less time across the entire workflow, remember that each single change in your will introduce bugs and in you have a monolithic approach you will regret this.

Comment: From my experience that approach still doesn't result in as little time spent waiting as can be had when working with Python or even C#.  The stark difference really struck me when I recently went back to a Python code base that was larger then the C++ code base I had just been working on, and I noticed it took less time to interpret the Python code and run the tests 4 different times (CPython, IronPython w/ 2 different flags, and Jython) then it took to build the smaller C++ code base for just the debug configuration of one platform.

Answer (score 2):

Continuous Integration is a rising concept today, so you are not alone here.

Assuming you are developing on Windows, if you are working with Microsoft Visual Studio
you may consider Microsoft's **[Visual Studio Team Foundation Server (TFS)](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-team-foundation-server-2012)**
(formerly *[Visual Studio Team System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fda2bad5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)*).
That will give you **Source-Control** AND **Build-Automation** in one package,
with great integration to Microsoft products, of course
(I think there is a free version for MSDN users).

If not keen on Microsoft products, or just looking for build-automation,
I would recommend a great **Open-Source Continues Integration** tool:
**[Jenkins CI](http://jenkins-ci.org/)**.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I would look at Jenkins CI - it is a good tool, works on any platform, and can be configured to do almost anything. I used it to run Python Code that talked to a mobile phone, made calls and recorded those calls (and tested the "quality" of the call, although my project never got the £xxxx real quality software, as we were just showing a concept), and then Jenkins would produce graphs of "how well it worked".

You can also do what you describe of "chaining" - so it would discover that your source has changed, try to build it [generally this is done using make, so it would automatically stop at the first errored file (although it could be hundreds of errors in one file!)]. Compile and build success then chains to running tests. Not entirely sure how you determine what is "relevant". If your test cycle isn't enormous, I'd run them all!